# Who is the Goddess Vimala's husband?

Tags: vishnu, shiva

I found about this new Goddess called Vimala, who is worshiped with Jagganath at Puri. She is said to be a "Tantric" goddess. However,there is a confusion between who her husband is, Shiva or Vishnu/Jagganath. Who is her real husband?

Comment: Where did you came to know about Goddess Vimala?

Comment: BTW,Goddess Kamala ,who is one among the Dasa Mahavidyas, is considered to be the "Tantrik Laksmi".

Comment: When i wa sresearching on Jagganath,Puri.

Comment: Does anybody know the answer

Comment: From wiki i found the following: "According to Starza (author of The Jagannatha Temple at Puri), the Jagannath Temple was once a centre of worship for the Trimurti of Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva, along with their consorts and the three central forms of the Hindu Goddess, Sarasvati, Lakshmi and Parvati (in the form of Vimala)"So Lord Shiva is the answer you are looking for.:)

Comment: However,according to the Tantriks,and some people in Puri,Vimala is Jagganth's wife